# Canvas how to zoom in particular place?

Tags: html, canvas

I have a canvas image as below, when I zoom the image using canvas scale, the image keeps on zoom to the position number 1(top left corner) of the image , but I would like to zoom to the position such as number 2 (middle) or number 3 (bottom right) corner , how can I achieve this ?

I already tried the method of transform, translate ...but none of it working.

Below is my code :

```js
var offset = {
  offsetX: 0,
  offsetY: 0
}

var translate = {
  translateX: 0,
  translateY: 0
}

function draw() {
  ctx.save();

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);

  ctx.setTransform(scale, 0, 0, scale, translate.translateX, translate.translateY);
}

// when zoom in 
document.getElementById("zo").addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (scale >= 2) {
    translate.translateX = 0;
    translate.translateY = 0;

    scale /= scaleFactor;

    draw();

    zoomLevel -= 1;

    $("#zoomLevel").text("Zoom Level " + zoomLevel);
  }
}, false);

//when zoom out
document.getElementById("zi").addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (scale < 8) {
    scale *= scaleFactor;
    //ctx.translate(500,500);
    translate.translateX = 0;
    translate.translateY = 0;
    // ctx.translate(transform.x , transform.y);
    draw();
    zoomLevel += 1;
    $("#zoomLevel").text("Zoom Level " + zoomLevel);
    console.log("Scale" + scale);
  }
}, false);
```

Anything missing in my code? I have no idea why the zooming to a particular place is not working. Thanks in advance

[image: Canvas]

Comment: Please include an [MCVE]. Here we are missing some parts that might have importance (for instance you never actually *draw* anything). But from here, I'd say, change transform.translateX and transform.translateY to the coordinates you want your transform origins from.

Comment: Sorry , I'm not so good in canvas , anything that I miss ?? Please let me know I will include it .. I've tried the transform things you mention , but it did not change the zoom scale but it did change how my image was display..

Comment: In the code you gave, you are not drawing anything on your canvas. The `draw` function only clears the canvas and set its transformation matrix, so the next time the clearRect will get affected by this transform, but since there is nothing drawn, that won't really matter...

Comment: okay , what I want to achieved is zoom on particular area, for example now my zoom is always focus on top left corner which is x = 0 , y = 0 , i tried to changed the value ,  but the zoom area is not changed instead it changed the background image.if I wish to zoom on middle , how can i achieved it ?? can I have a example on JS fiddle or codepen ?

Comment: You need to setup this example. We won't do it all for you.

Comment: Actually I have no idea how to achieved that , nvm is okay..I will tried it ..thanks a lot..